# Trouble with sorting in a Binary Search tree

Tags: java, sorting, binary-search-tree

I've been having trouble making this binary search tree work. The idea is that a person is put in and then sorted based on their name.

The class I am using for person is:

```
package Tree;

public class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private String gender;

    public Person( String name, String gender,int age) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [age=" + age + ", name=" + name + ", gender="
                + gender + "]";
    }
}
```

and the Search tree is:

```
package Tree;

public class BinarySearchPerson {

private boolean empty;
private Person person;
private static BinarySearchPerson left;
private static BinarySearchPerson right;

public BinarySearchPerson(Person person, BinarySearchPerson left,
        BinarySearchPerson right) {
    this.empty = false;
    this.person = person;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}

public BinarySearchPerson() {
    this.empty = true;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return empty;
}

public Person getPerson() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Trying to access root of an empty tree");
    }
    return person;
}

public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
}


public BinarySearchPerson getLeft() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                                        "Trying to access subtree of an empty tree");
    }
    return left;
}


public void setLeft(BinarySearchPerson left) {
    this.left = left;
}


/**
 * gets the right subtree of this node
 */
public BinarySearchPerson getRight() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                                        "Trying to access subtree of an empty tree");
    }
    return right;
}


public void setRight(BinarySearchPerson right) {
    this.right = right;
}



public static BinarySearchPerson insert(Person person, BinarySearchPerson bt){
    int n = person.getName().compareTo(bt.person.getName());


    if (n<0){
        if(bt.getLeft().isEmpty() == true){
            bt.setLeft(new BinarySearchPerson(person,new BinarySearchPerson(),new BinarySearchPerson()));
            return bt;
        }
        else{
            return insert(person, bt.getLeft());

        }
    }

    if (n>0){
        if(bt.getRight().isEmpty() == true){
            bt.setRight(new BinarySearchPerson(person,new BinarySearchPerson(),new BinarySearchPerson()));
            return bt;
        }
        else{
            return insert(person, bt.getRight());
        }
    }
    else return bt;


}



}
```

The problem I am getting is to do with the sorting method called insert, near the bottom. For some reason it just makes an endless number of branches to the left or right depending on where the name is going to be sorted. I can't see where I am going wrong here so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the static modifier from

private static BinarySearchPerson left;
private static BinarySearchPerson right;

each node in the tree should have its own left and right.

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't see your code that actually calls insert initially, so I can't verify this.  However, what are you attempting to return from the insert method?  Shouldn't it be the newly created BinarySearchPerson?  If so, shouldn't you be returning the newly created element instead of the one you are currently on?  Also, the new BinarySearchPersons that you are creating don't have references to the previous ones.  You should need to do something like this (do this also for the right side):

```
if (n<0){
    if(bt.getLeft().isEmpty() == true){
        BinarySearchPerson newLeft = new BinarySearchPerson(person,new BinarySearchPerson(),bt);
        bt.setLeft(newLeft);
        return newLeft;
    }
    else{
        return insert(person, bt.getLeft());

    }
}
```